# How exclude one term from get_terms

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy-terms

I am showing a list of terms from a taxonomy and need to exclude a term from the list how do I do this? I made the code below but did not delete it.

```
$terms = get_terms( 'taxonomyespecialidades', array( 
                        'orderby' => 'name',
                        'order'   => 'ASC',
                        'exclude'  => array(),
) );
$exclude = array("Acupuntura");
$new_the_category = '';
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
if (!in_array($term->term_name, $exclude)) {
$new_the_category .= '<div class="post hvr-grow"><li><strong><a id="lista" href="'.esc_url( get_term_link( $term ) ) .'">'.$term->name.'</a>'. ' ('. $term->count . ')</strong></li></div>';
}
}
echo substr($new_the_category, 0);
```

Comment: Enable error_reporting and debug modes when developing!  You try to access $term->term_name instead of $term->name, if you had error reporting on, it would have told this you were accessing an undefined property.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

You can **exclude multiple terms** from **get_terms** by putting their **id** and **slugs** in it.
for example:

```
// default to not exclude terms
$ids_to_exclude = array();
$get_terms_to_exclude =  get_terms(
    array(
        'fields'  => 'ids',
        'slug'    => array( 
            'Acupuntura', 
            'Acupuntura2', 
            'Acupuntura3',
            'Acupuntura4' ),
        //'taxonomy' => 'put taxonomy name here',
    )
);

if( !is_wp_error( $get_terms_to_exclude ) && count($get_terms_to_exclude) > 0){
    $ids_to_exclude = $get_terms_to_exclude; 
}
$terms = get_terms( 'taxonomyespecialidades', array( 
                        'orderby' => 'name',
                        'order'   => 'ASC',
                        'exclude'  => $ids_to_exclude,
) );
```

Comment: Can you do this using the words of the terms?

Comment: I have edited my answer, Now you can put their slug name in first function and it will pass the excluded id to the next function. I hope this will work for you...